# Check if a series can be made or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms

Given an infinite geometric sequence $S=\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \dots \}$.

I need to tell whether for given fraction $p⁄q$, we can select an infinite geometric sequence $R$, such that $R \subset S$ and Summation of all elements in $R$ is $p/q$.

Example : 
If $p=3$ and $q=1$ then answer would be "NO" as There cannot exist any series with sum as 3, since maximum sum possible is 2.

If p=1 and q=3 then answer would be "Yes" as the series beginning with 1⁄4 and geometric factor as 1⁄4, has sum 1⁄3.

Constraints : $p,q \leq 10^9$.

Comment: Does $R$ have to be infinite?

Comment: @naslundx yes.series need to be infinite

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every real number in the interval $(0,1]$ has a *binary expansion* with infinitely many $1$s. Adjust for the fact that our series starts at $1$.

**Remark:** We have solved the problem for *any* infinite sequence. If *geometric* sequence is really intended, then there are far fewer numbers obtainable. For a geomeric sequence will have shape 
$$\frac{1}{2^a}+\frac{1}{2^{a+d}}+\frac{1}{2^{a+2d}}+\cdots.$$
This geometric sequence has sum
$$\frac{1}{2^a}\cdot \frac{2^d}{2^d-1},$$
giving sum $\frac{2^{d}}{2^a(2^d-1)}$.  Thus the fraction must have a denominator which is a power of $2$ times a number of the form $2^d-1$. And the numerator must be a power of $2$, with the restriction that the fraction must be $\le 2$.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit..Its being more than a day i am thinking of this question..:(

Comment: Please please explain more..I didnt get it yet

Comment: You presumably know what binary expansion (base $2$) means. Just like with decimals, numbers of the form $\frac{a}{2^k}$ have two expansions. In all other cases the binary expansion is unique.

Comment: i dont think am getting it till yet.Please explain by some example

Comment: For example, find the binary expansion of $1/3$. The smallest power of $\frac{1}{2}$ that is less than $1/3$ is $2$. Subtract $\frac{1}{2^2}$ from $1/3$. We get $\frac{1}{12}$. The smallest power of $\frac{1}{2}$ that is less than $\frac{1}{12}$ is $\frac{1}{2^4}$. Subtract $\frac{1}{2^4}$ from $\frac{1}{12}$. We get $\frac{1}{48}$. Continue. We conlude that $\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\cdots$. The same algorithm works in general. It is just like finding the decimal expansion of $\pi/10$=x$.(Cont)

Comment: Multiply $x$ by $10$, find the greatest integer which is $\le 10x$. This is $3$. Now calculate $10x-3=y$, find the greatest integer which is $\le 10y$. This is $1$. Now calculate $10y-1=z$. Find the greatest integer which is $\le 10z$. This is $4$. Continue. We get the decimal expansion of $\pi/10$, that is $0.3141592\dots$.

Comment: I just need to find wether series exist or not.I need not tell the series.How are u deciding for this decision?

Comment: In two comments ago, I forgot to mention that we get that the binary expansion of $1/3$ is $0.01010101\dots$.

Comment: The answer will be that such a series exists for all $x$ in the interval $(0,2]$. *Every* number $x$ in this interval has a binary expansion of shape $0.a_1a_3\dots$ or $1.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ with any $a_i$ equal to $0$ or $1$, and infinitely many $1$s. From this binary expansion you can read off the powers of $2$ needed.

Comment: so what to check to answer this problem.Conclude it now.Where to stop to check it?